# Unable to display a Google Sitelinks Search Box for my site

Tags: search, magento-2.2.5, search-terms, google

I have added below code in my homepage

```
    <![CDATA[
     <script type="application/ld+json">
     {
         "@context": "http://schema.org",
         "@type": "WebSite",
         "url": "https://www.example.com/",
         "potentialAction": {
         "@type": "SearchAction",
         "target": "https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q= 
         {search_term_string}",
         "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
         }
      }
</script>
]]>
```

Though not able to display google sitelinks search box while searching in google. Is there any change to be done.?

Answer (score 0):

[There's two thing to consider here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938725/9956270)

> 1. It can take Google a while to implement your code. I've seen it take a couple of months.
> 2. Adding sitelinks in the SERPs is at Google's discretion so having the code in your site is not a guarantee they will show sitelinks for
>      the site.

And Also Check [This Link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/6201185?hl=en)

Comment: Is it compulsory to verify app by adding this code <meta name="google-site-verification" content="zDB1hUVzbapEVom3sWPVt6yVKpt1lGKe_sF_yUF7TVE" />